# React Native: Custom Component for FlatList Content Container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Is there any way so that I can add a custom component for `FlatList` items?
I want to "wrap" my `FLatList` items with custom component equivalent to this

```
<ScrollView
    pt={8}
    px={16}
    pb={128}
>
    <Card elevate size='$2' bordered>
        <YGroup separator={<Separator />}>
            {data.map(({value, index}) => {
                <InterfaceItem ... />
            })}
        </YGroup>
    </Card>
</ScrollView>
```

Note that the items is "wrapped" inside `<Card>` and `<YGroup>` components
How can I achieve the same result by using FlatList?

I have tried wrapping the items with component in `renderItem` method, but the wrapper components get iterated too.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, then you just need to nest your `FlatList` inside of your wrappers if you do not want to render `Card` and `YGroup` as part of your iteration. This would look something like this:

```js
<Card elevate size="$2" bordered>
  <YGroup separator={<Separator />}>

    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return <InterfaceItem ... />;
      }}
    />

  </YGroup>
</Card>;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but It's not quite what I'm looking for.
Since the `<Card>` and `<YGroup>` are wrapping the `<FlatList>` component itself, then the `<FlatList>` lists will scroll inside of the `<Card>` and `<YGroup>` component as far as I know.